# ImageMagick convert jpx and jpf to jpg (Ubuntu 16)

Tags: imagemagick

I want to convert images with format `jpx` and `jpf` to `jpg` on Ubuntu 16.

After some research i found out that it is require `jp2` delegate. Right now when i executed command

`convert -list configure | grep DELEGATES`

i got this

`bzlib djvu mpeg fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr lzma openexr pango png ps rsvg tiff wmf x xml zlib`

How can i install `jp2` delegate on my system? Or if any other way to convert `jpf` and `jpx` to jpg, Please suggest me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

I am trying to get this working more simply, but only have a limited understanding of Ubuntu Package Managers. Here is my current, simplest, working solution.

### Step 1 - Install OpenJPEG2000 and all the build tools

Install v2.1 of OpenJPEG2000 Ubuntu 16 with:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libopenjp2-7 libopenjp2-7-dev
sudo apt-get install libopenjp2-7 libopenjp2-7-dev
sudo apt-get install build-essential pkg-config
```

### Step 2 - set PKG_CONFIG_PATH

That is good and it is the one ImageMagick needs, however, it seems maybe to be in a different place from where ImageMagick expects it. It is not in `/usr/lib` nor `/usr/local/lib`, but rather it is here:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenjp2.so.7
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenjp2.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libopenjp3d.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libopenjp2.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libopenjpip.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openjpeg-2.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenjp2.so.2.1.0
```

So, set your `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
```

### Step 3 - Install and build ImageMagick from source

```
cd
wget http://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz
tar -xzvf Im*gz
cd Image*[0-9]
./configure
make clean
make -j 8
sudo make install
```

---

**Original Answer - which works but is cumbersome**

Well, this was painful to work out but it works! Ubuntu 16 LTS

First, remove any dead versions of ImageMagick installed via `apt-get`.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge imagemagick
```

Then, make sure you have all the packages you need to build software with:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake pkg-config
```

Next, install JPEG200 library, version 2.1 or better!!!!

```
cd
wget https://github.com/uclouvain/openjpeg/archive/v2.1.2.tar.gz
gunzip open*gz
tar -xvf open*tar
cd open*2
mkdir build               # Out of source builds are preferred
cd build
cmake --prefix=/usr ..
make clean
make -j 8
sudo make install
```

Now, install ImageMagick:

```
cd
wget http://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz
gunzip Image*gz
tar -xvf *agick*tar
cd ImageMagick-7.0.4-6/
./configure --prefix=/usr
make clean
make -j 8
sudo make install
```

Now test:

```
identify -list configure | grep DEL
DELEGATES      mpeg jpeg openjp2 ps
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, I tried this and it works, but i can't use this solution. Can you tell me a solution directly via `sudo apt-get install *******` command?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about Ubuntu's package management system, yet. Maybe if we can get OpenJPEG2000 v2.1 http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety-updates/libopenjp2-7 installed first, then ImageMagick v7 afterwards, it will just work. The answer MAY include PPAs but I have never added one of those either. I will dink around on my VirtualBox Ubuntu later and see what I can do.